# Why its showing empty array?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, outliers, data-preprocessing

I am using z score method for outlier removal ..but I am getting the empty array when I set a threshold and printing the data below that threshold.
I tried below code.

```
from scipy import stats
z=np.abs(stats.zscore(df.High))
print(z)

threshold=7
print(np.where(z>7))
```

Its showing following output instaed of showing a array of a values.

```
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

Comment: Apparently none of the values are greater than 7.

Comment: No,there are values like 9,8,7 .The values are upto 9

Comment: You need to post the original data. Or a sampled version of the original data that causes the same issue.

Comment: Should O post data on stackoverflow?

Comment: You need to post something that runs and reproduces the error when run. That includes incorporating any necessary input.

Answer (score 0):

> Z-Score is essentially how many standard deviations away is my actual
> value from the mean value!

More on this [here](https://medium.com/clarusway/z-score-and-how-its-used-to-determine-an-outlier-642110f3b482). What you have done here is convert your population (column contains the values) to Z-scores and use an Actual value for threshold, but the threshold should be in Z-space either! This value is determined by the nature of the problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats 
mu, sigma = 5, 2
array = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 200)
df = pd.DataFrame(array, columns=["High"]) 
z=np.abs(stats.zscore(df.High))
print("Actual Value Above 7: ", df[df.High>7])
threshold=7
print("Z Score Value Above 7: ", np.where(z>threshold))
######## mapping 7 to Z space
z_threshold = (threshold - df.High.mean())/df.High.std(ddof=0)
print("Z Score Value Above zscore(7): ", np.where(z>z_threshold))
```